# dynamic class names in php

Tags: php, oop, wordpress

I have a base class called `field` and classes that extend this class such as `text`, `select`, `radio`, `checkbox`, `date`, `time`, `number`, etc.

Classes that extend `field` class are dynamically called in a directory recursively using `include_once()`. I do this so that I ( and others) can easily add a new field type only by adding a single file

What I want to know: Is there a way to substantiate a new object from one of these dynamically included extending classes from a variable name?

e.g. a class with the name `checkbox` :

```
$field_type = 'checkbox';

$field = new {$field_type}();
```

Maybe this would work? but it does not?

```
$field_type = 'checkbox';

$field = new $$field_type();
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This should work to instantiate a class with a string variable value:

```
$type = 'Checkbox'; 
$field = new $type();
echo get_class($field); // Output: Checkbox
```

So your code should work I'd imagine. What is your question again?

If you want to make a class that includes all extended classes then that is not possible. That's not how classes work in PHP.

Comment: I do not want to extend multiple classes, although this would not defeat OOP if it were possible. Some languages actually allow lultiple inheritance

Answer (score 25):

If you are using a namespace you will need to add it even if you are within the namespace.

```
namespace Foo;

$my_var = '\Foo\Bar';
new $my_var;
```

Otherwise it will not be able to get the class.

Comment: You can automatize for PHP >= 5.3 that with the [`__NAMESPACE__` constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php) : `$my_var = __NAMESPACE__ . '\Bar';`.

Answer (score 6):

just

```
$type = 'checkbox';
$filed = new $type();
```

is required. you do not need to add brackets

Answer (score 1):

You can also use reflection, `$class = new ReflectionClass($class_name); $instance = $class->newInstance(arg1, arg2, ...);`

Answer (score 1):

Spent some time figuring this out. From PHP documentation [Namespaces and dynamic language features](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php):

> Note that because there is no difference between a qualified and a
>   fully qualified Name inside a dynamic class name, function name, or
>   constant name, the leading backslash is not necessary.

```
namespace namespacename;
class classname
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo __METHOD__,"\n";
    }
}
function funcname()
{
    echo __FUNCTION__,"\n";
}
const constname = "namespaced";

/* note that if using double quotes, "\\namespacename\\classname" must be used */
$a = '\namespacename\classname';
$obj = new $a; // prints namespacename\classname::__construct
$a = 'namespacename\classname';
$obj = new $a; // also prints namespacename\classname::__construct

$b = 'namespacename\funcname';
$b(); // prints namespacename\funcname
$b = '\namespacename\funcname';
$b(); // also prints namespacename\funcname

echo constant('\namespacename\constname'), "\n"; // prints namespaced
echo constant('namespacename\constname'), "\n"; // also prints namespaced
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
$field_type = 'checkbox';
$field = new $field_type();
```

Code I tested it with in PHP 5.3

```
$c = 'stdClass';

$a = new $c();

var_dump($a);

>> object(stdClass)#1 (0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$field_type = 'checkbox';
$field = new $field_type;
```

If you need arguments:

```
$field_type = 'checkbox';
$field = new $field_type(5,7,$user);
```