# PHP class instantiation from variable and use keyword

Tags: php, objectinstantiation

could I ask about one clarification? At the top of my file i used (Silex context):
`use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;`

Lets say I have an array `$asserts` with asserts names as strings:

`'Assert\\NotBlank()', 
'Assert\\Date()'`

When I'm trying to

```
foreach($asserts as $constraint) {
  array_push($some_other_array, new $constraint)
}
```

I get **Class Assert\NotBlank() not found**, but when I make new instance explicitly

```
foreach($asserts as $constraint) { 
  array_push($some_other_array, new Assert\NotBlank())
}
```

everything works. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I tried with and without `()` <strike>and also with full paths to classes.</strike>

SOLUTION: An array of **full** paths without parentheses should be used.

```
'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank',
'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Date'
```

Best Regards,
Kamil

Comment: Loose the paranthesis at the end of class name in strings.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Do those classes have parameterless constructors?

Comment: Yes, [API](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/NotBlank.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try an array of:

```
'Assert\\NotBlank', 'Assert\\Date'
```

and:

```
array_push($some_other_array, new $constraint());
```

Per: [dynamic class names in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131295/dynamic-class-names-in-php)