# Declare class from Variable in PHP

Tags: php, class, variables, declaration

how can I declare new php class from string variable:

example:

```
$foo = 'Foo_Class';
if(!class_exists($foo)){
  class $foo extends Bar{}
}
```

Comment: May be duplicated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131295/dynamic-class-names-in-php

Comment: If the class_exists returns true, why would you then declare a new class of the same name, you would get an error. Surely you meant `new $foo()`

Comment: @RuchishParikh my question is different from that, What i want is Declare not instantiate.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea, that was my typo. sorry for confusion. I edited the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can only do this by using eval:

```
$foo = 'Foo_Class';
if(! class_exists($foo)){
  eval("class $foo extends Bar{}");
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend this aproach.

Comment: I would like to try this, but what security holes Im dealing with?

Comment: So far this is the only i know.

Comment: @J.Aries Maybe not strictly PHP, but here you will get basic understanding why eval overall is a bad practice: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/