# How to declare a class dynamically with a variable in php

Tags: php, elementor

I am trying to make a small script that will load php files and then initiate classes automatically. I am trying to do it like this,

```
$className = ucfirst($folderName).'()';
\Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new \Elementor\$className );
//HERE I AM GETTING ERROR BECAUSE OF THE $class VARIABLE USED.
```

The error I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$className' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

How can I get ride of the error and initiate the class?

Comment: Thanks. I am getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$className' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534159/instantiate-a-class-from-a-variable-in-php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131295/dynamic-class-names-in-php

Comment: Thank you. Solved the problem from this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php